# Preparing milestone timestamps for Sankey diagrams

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to map out how new users are moving through our different milestones, and I have been trying to generate the data through an SQL query, so it can feed into our visualisation in Google Charts.

Most users will pass through 7-10 key milestones, but they will do it in different orders.

I currently have the data in the following format:

```
user_id | milestone_x | milestone_y | milestone_z
1       | ts          | ts          | ts
2       | ts          | ts          | ts
...
```

And I am trying to create the following dataset for exporting to Google Charts:

```
(1) milestone_x | (2) milestone_y | 200
(1) milestone_x | (2) milestone_z | 150
(1) milestone_y | (2) milestone_x | 250
...
(2) milestone_y | (3) milestone_x | 50
...
```

.. so I can transform it into an array:

```
[
    ['(1) milestone_x', '(2) milestone_y', 200],
    ['(1) milestone_x', '(2) milestone_z', 150],
    ['(1) milestone_y', '(2) milestone_x', 250],
    ...
    ['(2) milestone_y', '(3) milestone_x', 50],
    ...
]
```

And put it in a Google Charts Sankey diagram.

I have been trying to make this work in SQL (Google BigQuery), but the only way I can figure it out would be to write out a line for each outcome, which isn't feasible with the amount of different paths.

Should I export the dataset and do it in another language/tool? Or is there a way to actually accomplish this in SQL?

Comment: What are (1) and (2) in your results?  Where do the numbers, such as 200 and 150 come from?

Comment: you should explain your data and expected result in more details!

Comment: The `(1)`, `(2)` etc. are meant to separate the milestones in the order that the companies reach them, so (1) milestone_x would be the companies that started with milestone_x, and (2) milestone_x would be if they hit the second milestone after reaching another milestone first.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like the average time to go from one milestone to the next -- but the order depends on the timestamps not the columns.

You can solve this by unpivoting the data, so there is one row per milestone.  Then enumerate the rows and use a self-join:

```
with data as (
      select 1 as user_id, 1 as milestone_x, 2 as milestone_y, 3 as milestone_z union all
      select 2 as user_id, 4 as milestone_x, 2 as milestone_y, 3 as milestone_z
     ),
     unpivoted as (
      select d.user_id, m.*, row_number() over (partition by d.user_id order by ts) as seqnum
      from data d cross join
           unnest(array[struct('milestone_x' as milestone, d.milestone_x as ts),
                        struct('milestone_y', milestone_y),
                        struct('milestone_z', milestone_z)]
                 ) m
     )
select u1.milestone, u2.milestone, avg(u2.ts - u1.ts) as diff
from unpivoted u1 join
     unpivoted u2
     on u1.user_id = u2.user_id and
        u1.seqnum = u2.seqnum - 1
group by u1.milestone, u2.milestone
```

Comment: Not quite - I am just looking for the different paths through the milestones. So one user will have a path like.. ( x -> y -> z), another will have a path like ( y -> z - x ), and I want to display in a Sankey diagram what the most common journeys look like.